# IB not responding to UIImageView moving

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uiimageview

This an incredibly annoying bug. I had a imageView and 2 Labels in a customCell nib. I changed the locations of all of them in the nib and the labels moved, view didn't.

I've cleaned my targets, deleted everything relating to it the library, deleted the cell completely, reset the simulator, built it on a different target (3.1.2) and it still compiles the image in the same stupid spot.

Can anyone help this is nuts.

Sorry for being blunt but completely frustrated.

Edit: I have deleted the nib and created it over again by hand, but with the same names. Doesn't fix it. I've checked to see if im moving it somewhere in the code and no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I was actually setting the default tablecell property image. Wasn't obvious to me as the original location of the image was unintentionally the default location and size (pretty much) and I moved it to the opposite side though still setting the default image and not the custom one. Having a custom cell too I didn't realise that the image property was still available.

Answer (score 0):

It moves in IB right ? Just goes back to where it was when executed ?

The first thing that springs to mind is that it is being (re)positioned by code - is anything messing with its frame ?

The other option is that its the parent frame that is being moved, putting the image back where it was.

If not, I'd probably re-build the XIB from scratch, assuming its not too complicated.

Comment: I've now tried to rebuild it from scratch and no change. Looked inside the nib and the source code and its set to the correct place. this is incredibly frustrating

Comment: And yes to your first 2 questions

Comment: sorry I have no further idea at this stage